# Error in gitlab fatal Couldn't find remote ref

Tags: linux, git, gitlab, pipeline, runner

I have created a runner and set up a pipeline for my master repository in production. While running the pipeline I am facing an issue saying **fatal: Couldn't find remote ref**.

## [fatal: Couldn't find remote ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNfXy.png)

I have tried to clone from Linux it is working also I have checked the connection. Can anyone have any idea how to proceed?

```
image: maven:3.6.2-jdk-8

default:

stages:
    - build_prod
    - deploy_prod
    - run_prod


variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"
  GITLAB_BASE_URL: "https://gitlab.com"


build_prod:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - git submodule update --remote
  only:
     variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  tags:
      - prod    
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -f build.pom.xml -P prod
  environment:
    name: production
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/dev-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
  when: manual
  only:
  - master

  
deploy_prod:    
    stage: deploy
    only:
      variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    tags:
      - prod
    variables:
      GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
      - cp /home/gitlab-runner/builds/UtZuJjHy/0/dev/backend/target/LXRLite-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /home/gitlab-runner/patch/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/
      - cd /home/gitlab-runner
      - sh key.sh
    environment:
      name: production
    when: manual
    only:
    - master


    
run_prod:
    stage: run
    only:
      variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    tags:
      - prod
    variables:
      GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
      - ls
      - cd /home/gitlab-runner
      - sh keycomp.sh $DEPLOY_KEY
    #   - cp /home/gitlab-runner/patch/master/dev-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /disk2/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
    #   - sh tomcat_restart.sh
    environment:
      name: production
    when: manual  
    only:
    - master
```

Comment: what is the full git command that is being run there?

Comment: I am running from Gitlab, Please check the .yml file